# Debugging remote process running on Ubuntu VM via Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a c++ aplication, it'a VS project. I'm able to compile/run it on Windows system, same case for Ubuntu.
Is it possibile to attach to remote process on Ubuntu VM and debug it via Visual Studio ?
Thanks

I tried using the MS guide, but it requires solutions to be cross-platform MakeFile Projekt (GBD) template.

Comment: which official document you were referring to? this document seems not limited to GBD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2022